# is there a way to get the applicationId of current product flavor in AndroidManifest file?

Tags: android, android-manifest, build.gradle

I have 4 product falvors and each one obviously has 4 different applicationIds in build.gradle. I need to get them in my Manifest file.

Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Why do you need them in the manifest? The gradle settings will determine your package name and such on its own

Comment: Actually I am using a library and it sends intent back to my application when the user taps on an audio file. I am trying to add an intent filter in my manifest. The intent is created as follows:
intent.setAction(getPackageName() + "intent.AUDIO");
this "getPackageName()" is returning my applicationId somehow. And 4 products has 4 different application id, so I need them in manifest to create those intent filters.

Comment: I think the solution here is to not use `getPackageName()` at all and have consistent naming for your Intent Filters

Comment: @cricket_007 The reason was the library doesn't want some other application to listen to the same intent action. in other words, that library wants only the hosting application to receive the intent.

Comment: Right... but surely your flavors have the same "base" package name. The odds that you have some other application using the same string that you chose sounds rare.

Comment: Yes, it is rare; I agree.. But this is a Damn security flaw in my case.

Comment: Isn't using *${applicationId}* what you're looking for? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables.html

Comment: Thanks @Luksprog.. I am trying it now..

Comment: @Luksprog it worked... Thanks!
Please add your comment as answer.. I will accept it.

Comment: @Kannan_SJD What's the point of asking me to post an answer if you're not going to accept it?

Comment: @Luksprog Sorry man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *${applicationId}* in the manifest as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables.html) mentions:

> By default, the build tools also provide your app's application ID in
>   the ${applicationId} placeholder. The value always matches the final
>   application ID for the current build (including changes by build
>   variants. This is useful when you want to use a unique namespace for
>   identifiers such as an intent action, even between your build
>   variants.